# What are the chances of us changing the SFF logos/banners etc.?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The Gaming SE has **awesome** images that very clearly scream "gaming!":

[image][image]

Compare with SFF.SE's images:

[image][image]

- they're unclear/confusing [they don't "pop", you know?]
- they don't scream "sci-fi" or "fantasy"
- judging purely by the site's images, one could think this is a site devoted to

  1. the TV show *Supernatural*,
  2. ancient mythology, or even
  3. pagan/occult worship. :(

My sincerest apologies to whoever made these designs, but I just feel like SSF needs some images that clearly and immediately identify our site as being about sci-fi and fantasy. so...

## What are the chances of us changing them?

I'm not sure how that would all work but, can we be as cool as gaming.SE? Please?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sci-fi+fantasy&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTtd_3vrXLAhVQwmMKHaolBgYQ_AUIBygB&biw=1440&bih=815&safe=active&ssui=on#imgrc=M1qOJUpg1sYg2M%3A

Comment: They were designed by @Jin for when we graduated: [Design for Science Fiction & Fantasy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/976/21267). Also related: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/577/21267

Comment: My two cents: I like them. I know them. I *get* them.

Comment: I don't particularly like Arqade's theme, so I hope we don't move to a theme similar to theirs. Also, I imagine to anyone young who isn't familiar with 8-bit games or Defender, they are wondering why the theme looks so retro or dumpy.

Comment: @JackBNimble "anyone young who isn't familiar with 8-bit games" anyone who's interested enough in gaming to go to gaming.SE will definitely already know about 8-bit games. :)

Comment: @RedCaio I wouldn't necessarily assume that someone Googling a question about Battlefield 8-bajillion and coming to the site is also an avid gamer who loves retro games.

Comment: @JackBNimble go anywhere to buy games, like gamestop etc., and BAM - there are retro/8-bit gaming images everywhere. :)

Answer (score 7):

I would imagine the chances are low.

The issue is that changing imagery of the site serves no large purpose,  even less so know that you don't need it for graduation from a beta site anymore. Not to mention the backlog for site designs.

Also those who are requesting the change are viewing it differently to those who've been on the site longer and may have grown fond of it.

I would not at all attribute arqade's success on their design,  as having itself lends itself to a more interactive format requiring Q&A.

That said I'm very fond of RPG.SE's design.

[image: the banner for RPG.SE]